# How to parse html table (from file) by specific ID

Tags: c#, html, database, html-agility-pack

I am trying to get specific table (by id) from downloaded html and parse it I´ve tried few ways and my last code is

```
            var url = @"C:\Users\name\Plocha\web.html";

        var doc = new HtmlDocument();

        doc.Load(url);

        string data = "";
        int i = 2;
        foreach (HtmlNode table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Found: {table.Id}");
            if (table.Id == "formTbl")
            {
                foreach (HtmlNode row in table.SelectNodes("//tr"))
                {
                    foreach (HtmlNode cell in row.SelectNodes("td"))
                    {
                        if (i == 1)
                        {
                            data += $"Column:{cell.InnerText}";
                            i = 2;
                        }
                        else if (i == 2)
                        {
                            data += $"Row: {cell.InnerText}";
                            Console.WriteLine(data);
                            data = "";
                            i = 1;
                        }
                        
                        
                            
                    }
                    
                    
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Not what we want");
            }



        }
```

The problem is that it print all tables from webpage even tho I have specified to continue only if id = formTbl.

How data looks on table (theres no Name of columns its just two rows, in first row is name of column and in second row is value)
[image: Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectNodes()` takes an `XPath` query. Some useful [examples here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp). A particular one that is relevant to your case is this: *`//book` - Selects all book elements **no matter where they are in the document**.*

This means that instead of using `"//tr"` (searches the whole doc), you should look for `"tr"` if you want to respect the scope.

You could even use xpath to do the `id` searching AND selecting the `<tr>` underneath, using a single query:

```cs
foreach (var row in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='formTbl']/tr"))
{
    // ...do <tr> stuff
    foreach (var cell in row.SelectNodes("td"))
    {
        // ... do <td> stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I got exception System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Not really sure what´s wrong with it. https://pastebin.com/USa7xDHS

Comment: @Justyn it's case-sensitive. Is your table id `formtbl` or `formTbl`?

Comment: Yeah I think it is   <table class="ms-formtable" style="margin-top: 8px;" border="0" cellpadding="0" id="formTbl" cellspacing="0" width="100%">

Comment: @Justyn well the code you linked on pastebin had it as lowercase

Comment: Well, here is my code, I tried new one but not really working: https://pastebin.com/T5TGganw

Comment: Here is, how it looks like https://pastebin.com/rZk5a68d (its not full html, its edited with main stuff), and I cant edit html, since I need to use this code for few more html which are same, just with diff values. That´s why I am trying to find way to parse it, to be able to just parse many tables from pasted links)

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var table in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[@id='formTbl']"))
{
    foreach (var row in table.SelectNodes("tbody/tr"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(row.Id);
        foreach (var cell in row.SelectNodes("td"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(cell.InnerText);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem was that I hasn't used tbody/tr

Thanks to @NPras